# Detect if device has scroll events enabled

Tags: javascript, mobile, scroll, ios8, browser-feature-detection

With iOS8 out and now supporting live scroll events (hurray!), there is now a lot more reason to include scroll events on the mobile websites.

I'm looking for a clean and simple way to detect if the browser has scroll events enabled or disabled, so that I can include fallbacks for browsers that don't support this glorious feature.

The only way I have come up with so far is to start tracking the scroll with javascript and clock how many events are fired. There has to be a better way though.

Comment: I can't think of a better way either...

Comment: I guess most android browsers have good scroll events, so for now i will just apply fallbacks for < iOS8